# how to access attribute of table using string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have bakery table in which one column name is open_su which i can access using `Spree::Bakery.first`.

and o/p is.

```
   #<Spree::Bakery id: 2, open_su: "10:30am", open_mo: "10:30am", open_tu:    "10:30am", open_we: "10:30am", open_th: "10:30am", open_fr: "9:30am", open_sa: "10:30am", closed_su: "9:00pm", closed_mo: "9:00pm", closed_tu: "9:00pm", closed_we: "9:00pm", closed_th: "9:00pm", closed_fr: "9:00pm", closed_sa: "9:00pm">
```

and i access open_su column using - Spree::Bakery.first.open_su
o/p is

but i have one instance variable @time which have value is "10:30am"

so how can i access `Spree::Bakery.first.@time`

this in `@time` value is comes dynamically

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ruby objects have a `.send` method which can can be used to dynamically call methods.

```
Spree::Bakery.first.send(@time.to_sym)
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, trying to write from my phone and it doesn't want to cooperate. The key difference between using send and instance_variable_get is that send will call the getter method instead of breaking encapsulation.